# Flutter laggy navigation

Tags: flutter, materialpageroute

I have this auto platform detect navigation function but when I use it for the iPhone on release mode it lags but when I make it only with `MaterialPageRoute` it doesn't lag at all on iOS.

```
static navigateTo({BuildContext context, Widget w, bool fullscreenDialog}) {
    Platform.isIOS
    ? Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => w, fullscreenDialog: fullscreenDialog))
    : Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => w, fullscreenDialog: fullscreenDialog));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over time, it seems that this issue was being addressed on the latest versions of Flutter. Try to [upgrade](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/upgrade) your Flutter:

```
 flutter upgrade
```

If you will be running it on the latest iOS release, chances are you will also be getting the same issue. With that, [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/131319) is a workaround that you can explore.